# How to make a generic enum Equatable in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, swift3, enums, extension-methods

Having a generic enum `Result<T>`

```swift
enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case error
}
```

How to make it conform to the `Equatable` protocol in Swift version 3 or higher?

---

I've tried the following:

```swift
extension Result: Equatable {
    static func ==<T: Equatable>(lhs: Result<T>, rhs: Result<T>) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case let (.success(lhsVal), .success(rhsVal)):
            return lhsVal == rhsVal
        case (.error, .error):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

However, this produces a compiler error: `Type 'Result<T>' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'`

I've also tried the following:

```swift
extension Result: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Result, rhs: Result) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case let (.success(lhsVal), .success(rhsVal)):
            return lhsVal == rhsVal
        case (.error, .error):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

However, this produces a compiler error: `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does it help to constrain the generic type to `Equatable`?

```
enum Result<T : Equatable> {
    case success(T)
    case error
}
```

Comment: Ah, it helps indeed. Thank you @vadian! Unfortunately, this means that I need to write the `Equatable` extension for `T` in the same project where the `Result` enum is defined. The reason that's a problem is that I only need the enum to be `Equatable` in my unit tests project, not in the app itself. Do you have any idea how to solve that, i.e. without adding Equatable unit test related code into the main codebase?

Comment: How do I make `Result` not always require an `Equatable`?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz If you don't need `Equatable` omit it.

Comment: I need `Result` to be `Equatable` when `T` is `Equatable`, but not `T` always being `Equatable`.

Comment: There is no *`maybe Equatable`*. You could add a second generic type which does not conform to `Equatable`.

Comment: What if my type T is Void? It should still be Equatable.

Comment: What about conforming `enum Result<F: FooProtocol>` to equatable?

Answer (score 4):

Write this extension without implementation:

```
extension Result: Equatable where T: Equatable {}
```

When `T` conforms to `Equatable`, `Result<T>` would conform to `Equatable` automatically.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! Looks like a sound advice. Unfortunately, I don't have Xcode at hand to test it out right now but will try to remember to get back to it.